# Access vue instance from handsontable

Tags: vue.js, handsontable

I am trying to set a vuejs variable from within handsontable.

The vuejs variable:

```
this.dataChanged
```

in code block below is not available from handsontable settings, any idea how can I access it?

```
<template>
<div id="hot-container">
<HotTable :root="root" :settings="hotSettings"></HotTable>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

data() {

return {
  #vuejs variable i want to set from hot
  dataChanged: false,
  root: 'test-hot',
  hotSettings: {
    data: [{something: 0}],
    afterChange: function(changes, src) {
      if (src !== 'loadData') {
        this.dataChanged = true
      }
},
methods: {
  saveChanges: function () {
    if (this.dataChanged){
      //save data
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code which uses handsontable with the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this same problem... I found a workaround posted on GitHub like so..

This way you can access all Vue's data, methods, etc as you normally would.

```
data() {
   return {
     hotSettings: {
       ...
       afterChange: this.afterChangeVue
       ...
     }
   }
},
methods: {
    afterChangeVue(changes, source) {
      console.log('changes, source => ', changes, source);
      console.log('this.$store => ', this.$store);
    },
```

Here is the link to the original thread: https://github.com/handsontable/vue-handsontable-official/issues/7#issuecomment-356190395

Answer (score 0):

I ended up saving to a variable declared outside of vue - ie above the data () declaration

```
var myNewVar = 42
data() {
    #can save to myNewVar from here
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Rosdi_Kasim said, but much simpler with fat arrow function

```js
data() {
   return {
     hotSettings: {
       /*...*/
       afterChange: (changes, source) => {
         console.log('changes, source => ', changes, source);
         console.log('this.$store => ', this.$store);
       }
       /*...*/
     }
   }
},
methods: {
}
```